# vscode auto-import adding forward slash star (/*) to npm packages

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

Whenever I am auto importing certain in vscode it creates the correct import but adds `/*` to the end of the import statement, e.g.

```
import { Box } from '@cutting/component-library/*';
```

Here is a gif of what is happening

[image]